# How to sort 'mm-yyyy' format in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Date
01-2018
02-2018
01-2019
02-2019

I tried using arrange(df, Date)
It gets arranged as
01-2018
01-2019
02-2018
02-2019

Comment: That's not a date, it's just a string in a form that doesn't allow calendar sorting. If you want calendar sorting, use proper dates. Or reverse the parts of the string to look like `yyyy-MM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one base R option.  We can try ordering the data frame using an on the fly date based on the text strings.

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c("01-2018", "02-2018", "01-2019", "02-2019"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[order(as.Date(paste0("01-", df$Date), format="%d-%m-%Y")), ]

[1] "01-2018" "02-2018" "01-2019" "02-2019"
```

Note that I form a complete date by arbitrarily using the first of the month, for each text date, using `as.Date` with the correct format mask to generate a bona fide date.

For best results, consider storing your dates in a proper date column, or, if you must use text, use an ISO format which would at least sort properly.